# 3D Touch Quick Actions Always Going to Same Controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, 3dtouch, quickaction

Relatively new to Swift so sorry if this is obvious. Trying to create quick action links to open different tab views:

[Quick Action Links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLHNC.png)

When ever I try to open the action with this code though it always goes to the first quick action 'featured'??

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    if shortcutItem.type == "matthewfrankland.RonaldYule.contacts"{
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "contacts") as! Contact
        window?.rootViewController?.addChildViewController(vc)
    }

    if shortcutItem.type == "matthewfrankland.RonaldYule.allvideos" {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "allVideos") as! AllVideos
        window?.rootViewController?.addChildViewController(vc)
    }

    if shortcutItem.type == "matthewfrankland.RonaldYule.featured"{
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "featured") as! Featured
        window?.rootViewController?.addChildViewController(vc)
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're just adding the ViewControllers as children. Why don't you transition instead?

Comment: Yeah I tried transitioning but to the same effect